# Kendo Pie chart implementaion

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am creating a project using JavaScript with Kendo. I am the beginner in Kendo.

I have problem while integrating the pie chart.I want to this type of chart:
[image]

But when I integrate the code according to reference site then my chart shapes become:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var data = [
            {
                "source": "Hydro",
                "percentage": 22,
                "explode": true
            },
            {
                "source": "Solar",
                "percentage": 2
            },
            {
                "source": "Nuclear",
                "percentage": 49
            },
            {
                "source": "Wind",
                "percentage": 27
            }
        ];

        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Break-up of Spain Electricity Production for 2008"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                dataSource: {
                    data: data
                },
                series: [{
                    type: "pie",
                    field: "percentage",
                    categoryField: "source",
                    explodeField: "explode"
                }],
                seriesColors: ["#03a9f4", "#ff9800", "#fad84a", "#4caf50"],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "${ category } - ${ value }%"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your definition to remove shadow and border and keep the same skin

```
seriesDefaults: { 
                overlay: { gradient: "none" },
                border: {
                    width: 0,
                    color: ""
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only with the styling, you can set your chart theme. Just add `theme: "material"` and you should get a plain color.
A list of themes can be found on kendo UI docs https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling